How do I use the Kramers Konig transform to get absorption information from reflection data?
I have a wide range of reflection optical data from a sample, I would like to deduce the absorption coefficient from this data and my understanding is that I can use the K.K transformation to do this.
However, I have not really touched this branch of maths in a long time and I am unsure about how I handle the principle value in the equation.
Practicallly speaking, how do I implement the Kramers-Konig transform on a set of reflection data?

@LPZ, I don’t know the full scope of the KK transform but it is my understanding that is can be used with reflectance data: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dusan-Galusek/publication/249012208_What_is_the_true_Kramers-Kronig_transform/links/555c334208ae8f66f3ade5de/What-is-the-true-Kramers-Kronig-transform.pdf?origin=publication_detail&_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uRG93bmxvYWQiLCJwcmV2aW91c1BhZ2UiOiJwdWJsaWNhdGlvbiJ9fQ
